# Subquery inside an Access VBA DoCmd

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to run the following in Access / VBA

```
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLStatement:="INSERT INTO [Assets All] (RoomID) VALUES (SELECT RoomID from findNewRoomID )"
```

`findNewRoomID` is a Query and is part of the Form's Record Source, it only returns one result.

The error message says there is a syntax error in the subquery.

I have also tried with the SQL code of `findNewRoomID` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `VALUES` clause of an [`INSERT INTO`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-into-statement-e12fd58b-33b1-479c-8221-e9f245ab8d24) statement, a comma-delimited list of values should be supplied, and this can only be used to insert a *single* record into the target table.

If instead you wish to pass append the results of a `SELECT` query which may return multiple records, you would simply use:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Assets All] (RoomID) SELECT RoomID from findNewRoomID"
```

Comment: @IkerZuloBeltzak You're welcome! If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, I don't have voting privileges yet. I've now marked the answer as the solution. Thanks again.